# Launching an app with image data from an email

Tags: ios, email

I know I can launch an iOS app using URL Schemes embedded in an email.  How would I launch my app and pass it an image that is included in the email?  Can the URL reference the image in the email?  Or is it possible to automatically load the image to the clipboard?  I'm trying to do this in one step and not have the user manually tap and hold to put an image on the clipboard.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't be done. For some unknown reason, Apple has chosen not to offer the user the ability to send images to 3rd party apps. The Mail app doesn't support this for image attachments and the Photos app doesn't support it when sharing a photo.

Comment: Bummer!  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image is available from the web in some consistent format, perhaps it's best to:

1. Include the image's web address as part of the URL that opens your app
   (myapp://getImage/uniqueImagePath/)
2. Get the image path via the referrer
3. Add the base url (myphotohost.com) and extension (.jpg) to the path
4. Download the image client-side

The consistent format would be myphotohost.com/uniqueImagePath.jpg

[Here's a link that explains using an identifier (like uniqueImagePath in this context)](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-implement-deep-linking-ios/how-to/2015/07/14)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but in this case the image is only available in the email attachment.

Comment: okay, I see the issue. if UX is more important than the cost of hosting, hosting the images is a solution